# iOS - Re-populate data after didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, didreceivememorywarning, memory-warning

In my app I have several data objects stored in `NSMmutableArray's` that I clear by `removeAllObjects` in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` of my application. Also setting the tableview that displays the data to nil. How do I reload the data & views again?

I've read that only resources that can be recreated easily should be disposed off in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. I load the data array in `viewDidLoad` only. But this method is not called after `didReceiveMemoryWarning` so the data is never populated again.

Pardon me if this has been asked before, I've just not had a proper understanding from similar questions, still relatively new to iOS development.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I'm triggering memory warnings in the Simulator so I can learn and manage such conditions if they were to arise on actual usage of the app.

Comment: What about solving the memory management issue instead?...

Comment: Hi, my efforts to do that were by emptying the data array so as to free memory

Comment: @Sava Mazăre memory warning management is important even in the most efficient app : memory space left depends on much more than just what you personnally do in your app. Please read [this doc made by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html). Every one should do memory warning management, even you.

Comment: @Emilie, that guy has got serious memory management issues, his problem is somewhere in UITableViewCells' creation, reuse, bla-bla. One cannot just have an array of something and get memory warnings like this. P.S.: I am familiar to what that article says.

Comment: @Sava Mazăre I get your point. Solving memory issue is the first step, you're right. But after the memory issues are solved, memory warning management is important too and shouldn't be forgotten just because the app don't have memory issue anymore.

Comment: @Emilie, I've got your point as well, but working around "didReceiveMemoryWarning" will not solve his problem. Not entirely. He gotta learn how NOT to get memory warnings, and THEN to process any "potential", "future" memory issues.

Comment: @SavaMazăre I don't think the problem lies in the table cell creation. May I also add that I'm simulating memory warnings in order to learn how to handle them.

Comment: @user1868943, please, you don't have to simulate them. Make them happen normally, like in real life - this way you would have to face a "real" warning, which has to be handled. Make a mutable array and put a button which loads 10000 huge images into it; run on device, tap the button several times and watch your mem warnings arising "naturally".